# How does MongoDB match a document without a property with a null query

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp, mongodb-query

I have user controller and I written following find query with condition

```
$userData = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>null)));
```

If I written find query with `id=null` condition then also it return first record from database.

I expected no any record `because` condition is false, But it written first record.

My Question is why record is return from database and what is logic behind that ?

Generated **MongoDB query**

```
db.users.find( {"id":null}, [] ).sort( [] ).limit( 1 ).skip( 0 ).hint( [] );
```

**Update**

If I write following query with valid `user_id` then it return records.

```
$userData = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>"54c72b984a1bfeb420324670")));
```

Comment: Downvoter understand first my question after that you can downvoted.

Comment: What is the SQL being generated?

Comment: @AgRizzo check updated question with generated query.

Comment: Can you show us the document that is returned that you did not expect to be returned?

Comment: What people are asking is what document is returned where the field "id" is not null? I suspect this is just a typo and you just meant `"_id": null` instead. If there is no actual "id" field in the document it's still a valid query.

Comment: @NeilLunn If I write `array('id'=>"54c72b984a1bfeb420324670")` then It will return record.

Comment: @Sadikhasan I think you are missing the point. Added an answer for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @NeilLunn In my document `id` field does not exist then also it return record for `array('id'=>"54c72b984a1bfeb420324670")`. Why?

Comment: @Sadikhasan Read the answer I gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give an explaination you need to consider what is really happening here. Take these documents as an example:

```
{ "b": "a" },
{ "b": "a", "c": "d" }
```

If you basically form a query like this:

```
db.collection.find({ "c": "d" })
```

Then you get the second document as expected.

```
{ "b": "a", "c": "d" }
```

But if you query for a `null` on the same field:

```
db.collection.find({ "c": null })
```

You get the first document in response:

```
{ "b": "a" },
```

The reason is because the condition "is true". There is no field present in the document so MongoDB considers any test against a `null` value to prove the case that the field does not exist. Where the field does exist but does not contain a value of `null` then it would not match that condition and would not be returned.

So when you ask for values of fields that are not present in the document the internal evaluation is that the field "value" is actually `null`

Comment: what is output of  `db.collection.find({ "d": null })` and `db.collection.find({ "c": null })`  where `d` does not exist and `c` exist but do not contain `null` value?

Comment: That is what the answer says. `"d": null` would return every document where that field is not present. So all documents in this example. The `"c": null` example is already in the answer.

Comment: If I write `db.collection.find({ "c": null })` it returns all record where `c` is not present in `field`. As you say first document but it return all documents.

Comment: @Sadikhasan The "first document in my two document example". The point is if you query for a `null` value on a field that is not present in the document that **all** documents that do not contain that field or "do contain" the field **but** the value is actually there **will** be returned.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for help and giving your valuable time for explaination.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your index needs to be sparse in order to contain NULL values. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/#index-type-sparse

Then your generated query needs to look for a BSON type 10 i.e. NULL only, rather than NULL.

For example:

```
db.users.find( { id : { $type: 10 } }, []).sort([]).limit(1).skip(0).hint [] )
```

Without these settings in place your query is correctly finding the first record which is either NULL or not NULL.

Comment: The index needs to be sparse in order to omit documents with missing values; documents with `null` field values are included in sparse and non-sparse indexes. In version >= 2.6, moreover, a sparse index on `a` won't be used for a search like `{ "a" : null }` that might omit results.